# How to use long path in XmlDocument.Load()?

Tags: c#

I have a long-long path

```
var path = "\\?\C:\long\paht\to\file\myxml.xml"
```

I trying to read it:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(path);
```

And get exception here:

```
system.uriformatexception invalid uri the hostname could not be parsed
```

Everything else work with long path, but `XmlDocument.Load()` doesn't. What should i do here? Open file in regular stream and use `xmlDoc.Load(stream)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to answer your question i would refer [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later) which states 2 prerequisites you must satisfy, in order to enable Long Path on **Windows 10 from version 1607 on**.
Supposing you already done those additional required settings, there's an option mostly probable that's the currently missing  support in the underlying implementation of XmlDocument's Load method.

I've done your same test, in environment targeting .Net 4.6.2+ which doesn't require any additional config in the application config file (which would been required otherwise):

```
  var path = @"\\?\C:\long\paht\to\file\myxml.xml";
  var xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
  //xmlDoc.Load(path); => it breaks as you have seen
  // avoid exception check for brevity
  FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
  xmlDoc.Load(fs);
```

This way you should been able to read the file you need and with, good code management, remove the unnecessary intermediate passage currently required.

Comment: @lisnsock year i forgot to note that i use .Net 4.5.2 so i added long path support in app.xml. And in the end use same solution as in your answer. I just hoped that  i missed something and it's possible jsut use XmlDocument's Load with long path.